# interface does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, object | undefined>'. Index signature is missing in type 'StackParamList'.ts(2344)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

With TypeScript 3.9, React Native, React Navigation...

I got error:

```
interface StackParamList
Type 'StackParamList' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, object | undefined>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'StackParamList'.ts(2344)
```

on:

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>()
```

In:

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator<StackParamList>()

export interface StackParamList {
  Home: undefined
  Post: { post: Post }
  Category: { category: Category }
  Login: undefined
  ForgotPassword: undefined
  'My profile': undefined
  'My partner': undefined
  Parameters: undefined
  Likes: undefined
  Onboarding: undefined
}

/**
 * Home "stack navigator"
 * @summary this is the navigator for everything located under "home"
 */
export default function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={colors.background} barStyle="dark-content" />
      <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
        <HomeStack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            headerTitle: (props) => <Logo {...props} />,
          }}
        />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Post" component={PostScreen} options={{ headerTransparent: true, title: '' }} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Category" component={CategoryScreen} options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.category.id })} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="My profile" component={UserProfileScreen} options={{ headerTransparent: true, title: '' }} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="My partner" component={UserPartnerScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Parameters" component={UserParamScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Likes" component={UserLikesScreen} />
        <HomeStack.Screen name="Onboarding" component={Onboarding} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </HomeStack.Navigator>
    </>
  )
}
```

I don't understand why the interface would not satisfy the type 'Record<string, object | undefined>'.

I don't understand what "Index signature is missing" mean.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the interface to type. [Here's the link to the StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903342/react-navigation-typescript-error-type-eventstackparams-does-not-satisfy-th/64903574#64903574)

**Error Fix:**

```
// TypeScript Type: Stack Param List
export type StackParamList = {
  Home: undefined
  Post: { post: Post }
  Category: { category: Category }
  Login: undefined
  ForgotPassword: undefined
  'My profile': undefined
  'My partner': undefined
  Parameters: undefined
  Likes: undefined
  Onboarding: undefined
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue with useParams Hook in React (react-router-dom):

You can't use Interface in Generic for useParams Hook, only type object, if you check useParams in details:

useParams: export function useParams<Params extends {[K in keyof Params]?: string} = {}>(): Params;

If you pay attention on restriction in Generic extends {[K in keyof Params]}
you will see that in Interface we can't use computed properties [K in keyof...] but in "type object" we can. That's why there's an error in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

**context**

- this is needed if you have `'plugin:@typescript-eslint/strict',` within your eslint config
- normally, this work fine if you pass a `type`, however, if you pass an `interface`, you need to `extends ParamListBase`

**before**

```
export interface UnAuthStackRoutes {
  debug: undefined;
  'forgot-password': { email: string };
  landing: undefined;
  onboarding: undefined;
  privacy: undefined;
  'sign-up': undefined;
  terms: undefined;
}
```

**after**

```
export interface UnAuthStackRoutes extends ParamListBase {
  debug: undefined;
  'forgot-password': { email: string };
  landing: undefined;
  onboarding: undefined;
  privacy: undefined;
  'sign-up': undefined;
  terms: undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the reason, but i solved it by adding

```
[key: string]: any;
```

to the interface

```
interface loginFormData {
    email: FormDataEntryValue;
    password: FormDataEntryValue;
    [key: string]: any;
  };
```

I searched the reason, got this article https://dev.to/tlylt/exploring-key-string-any-in-typescript-4ake , but did not understand it.

If anyone reads it, or gets a clarity on the reason for it, please write/explain the reason for it

Answer (score -2):

I got this solved by adding:

```
| Record<string, object | undefined>
```

On:

```
export type StackParamList =
  | {
      Home: undefined
      Post: { post: Post }
      Category: { category: Category }
      Login: undefined
      ForgotPassword: undefined
      'My profile': undefined
      'My partner': undefined
      Parameters: undefined
      Likes: undefined
      Onboarding: undefined
    }
  | Record<string, object | undefined>
```

I still don't really understand why it was needed...