# React Navigation + TypeScript Error: Type 'EventStackParams' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, object | undefined>'

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, typescript-typings, react-navigation-v5

I'm adding TypeScript to my React Native/React Navigation 5 Navigator, but having an issue with Adding `EventStackParams` to the `createStackNavigator()`.

I've looked through the [React Native 5 Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/), StackOverflow, and GitHub, but no luck. What am I doing wrong? Below is my error and the code

**Error:**

```
Type 'EventStackParams' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, object | undefined>'.

Index signature is missing in type 'EventStackParams'.ts(2344)
```

**Navigation.tsx:**

```
// Imports: TypeScript Types
import { EventStackParams } from '../types/types';

// React Navigation: Stack Navigators
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
const EventsStack = createStackNavigator<EventStackParams>();

// Events Navigator
const EventsNavigator = () => (
  <EventsStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Events">
    <EventsStack.Screen
      name="Events"
      component={Events}
      options={{
        title: '',
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />

    <EventsStack.Screen
      name="EventDetails"
      component={EventDetails}
      options={{
        title: '',
        headerShown: true,
        headerStyle: {
          elevation: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          borderBottomWidth: 0,
        },
      }}
    />
  </EventsStack.Navigator>
);
```

**EventDetails.tsx**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

// Imports: TypeScript Types
import { ReduxState, EventStackParams } from '../../types/types';

// React Hooks: React Navigation
const route = useRoute<RouteProp<EventStackParams, 'EventDetails'>>();
```

**Types.tsx:**

```
// TypeScript Type: Event
export interface Event {
  eventTitle: string,
  eventDescription: string | null,
  eventStreet: string,
  eventLocation: string,
  eventLatitude: number,
  eventLongitude: number,
  eventDateStart: number,
  eventDateEnd: number,
  eventTimeStart: string,
  eventTimeEnd: string,
};

// TypeScript Type: Event Stack Params
export interface EventStackParams {
  Events: undefined,
  EventDetails: {
    item: Event,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

This was fixed by changing the `interface` to `type`.

```
// TypeScript Type: Event Stack Params
export type EventStackParams = {
  Events: undefined,
  EventDetails: {
    item: Event,
  },
};
```

Comment: yep, this is the correct answer, thanks!
I guess when you are using a `type alias` instead of an `interface`, you don't have to implement the index signature required in ```typescript string | Record<string, string | undefined>```